# (Laravel 5.3) ReflectionException in Route.php line 333: Method App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController::profile () does not exist

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I can't seem to find a solution which results in the dismal of this error:

> ReflectionException in Route.php line 333: Method App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController::profile () does not exist*

**web.php**
[image: web.php]

**ProfileController.php**
[image: ProfileController.php]

I've also used artisan to scaffold the resource controllers.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve : ReflectionException in Route.php line 333: Method App\Http\Controllers\PerekamanController::show() does not exist" in Laravel 5.3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41069673/how-to-resolve-reflectionexception-in-route-php-line-333-method-app-http-cont)

Comment: What is the output of `php artisan route:list`?

Comment: @AmitGupta the output is:

[img]http://i.imgur.com/ad73XhF.jpg[/img]

Comment: I embedded the images, but please add your code as text not as image.